# Django cms clear plugin level cache

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a custom plugin which is basically rendering a form, I had it published over a page from where i removed it later. Problem I am facing is 
when I see published page the plugin part is till there being rendered, and when i go to modify it there is no existence of plugin.

I assume it is a django cms's plugin level cache's problem which i am unable to flush.
I've used `cache = False` , `CMS_PLUGIN_CACHE` , `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CACHE` but no help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically you could invalidate the cache of the placeholder the plugin is in by doing something like;

```
from cms.cache.placeholder import clear_placeholder_cache

clear_placeholder_cache(my_placeholder, 'en', 1)
```

Where you pass the instance of the placeholder the plugin is attached to, language code & site ID. This example is used in the [CMS test suite](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/tests/test_cache.py#L707).

There is also a [`clear_cache`](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/placeholdermodel.py#L483) method on the `Placeholder` model;

```
def clear_cache(self, language, site_id=None):
    if not site_id and self.page:
        site_id = self.page.node.site_id
    clear_placeholder_cache(self, language, get_site_id(site_id))
```

This method is called by [`mark_as_dirty()`](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/placeholdermodel.py#L488) on the placeholder.